# Excel SUMIFS for cells for which header contains a string, but return NA if any selected cell contains NA

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a sumifs formula that sums cells for which the header contains a specified string (eg, "EC"), but I want it to return "NA" or error if any of THOSE cells contains NA (missing data).

My dataframe is somewhat like this:

```
ID | EC1 | INH2 | EC3

A | 100 | 200 | 100 

B | 200 | 100 | NA

C | 200 | NA | 100
```

Ideal totals would look like this:

```
ID | ECtot | INHtot

A | 200 | 200

B | NA | 100

C | 300 | NA
```

Formula 1 I have tried:

```
=sumif([#headers][df], "*STRING*", [@df])

Actual: =SUMIF(Table1[[#Headers],[1.EC.N]:[75.TM.I]],"*EC*",Table1[@[1.EC.N]:[75.TM.I]])
```

Result: This sums all columns containing the string as though NA = 0; I need it to return an error or NA if any column containing the string also contains NA.

Example Result:

```
ID | ECtot | INHtot

A | 200 | 200

B | 200 | 100

C | 300 | NA
```

Formula 2:

```
=if(countblank([@df})=0, sumif([#headers][df], "*STRING*", [@df]))

Actual: =IF(COUNTBLANK(Table1[@[1.EC.N]:[75.TM.I]])=0, SUMIFS(Table1[@[1.EC.N]:[75.TM.I]],Table1[[#Headers],[1.EC.N]:[75.TM.I]],"*Inh*"))
```

Result: This returns FALSE if any cell in the entire row contains NA, not just those with the string, else returns correct sum.

Example Result:

```
ID | ECtot | INHtot

A | 200 | 200

B | NA | NA

C | NA | NA
```

Anyone have any ideas how to consolidate these 2 issues?  Otherwise I'll have to sum these manually, but that involves human error (75 columns).

Also open to solutions involving R, if anyone knows any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question. Easy solution, use formula #1, and make all NA's -9999 (since values cannot be negative in this case).  Then replace all sums that are negative with NA.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't figured out how to get it to count -only- the NA's in the cells specified.  I have figured out how to check if there are -any- NA's in the entire row, but not for only the cells being added.  I've fooled with so many combinations of AND, OR, IF, COUNTIF(S), and SUMIF(S), I don't know where to begin with what I've tried.

This is working, but it's sure inelegant.

Comment: Thanks! This does work, if I create an extra column for each subscale (so one column for counting NA's, one for sumif, wrapped in an extra if statement).  Regardless, I can put data in, and get scores out, without any extra steps in between (meaning other people can actually use it easily).